# XAML binding not firing on a model implementing INPC

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have an observable collection of models.
these models implement INPC
Inside the data templates of the List which contains the collection, I set a property of the item to change when the list item is clicked.
The on property changed event is fired, but the XAML is never updated. 
Does someone have a solution please ?

```cs
//The observable collection
private ObservablePagedList<ProposalModel> _proposals;

        public ObservablePagedList<ProposalModel> Proposals
        {
            get => _proposals;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _proposals, value);
        }
```

Inside the XAML, I set a collection view with a button whose property change depending on the a property of the item to which it is binded.

```html
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Proposals}"
                Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            
                            ...
                            ...
                            
                                        <Button Text="{markupExtensions:Translate Accept}"
                                                Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AcceptProposalCommand, Source={x:Reference _myAnnDetailsPageklas}}"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                            <Button.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button"
                                                             Binding="{Binding Path=State, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                             Value="{x:Static models:ProposalStates.Approved}">
                                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{markupExtensions:Translate Reject}"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Source={x:Reference _myAnnDetailsPageklas}, Path=BindingContext.RejectProposalCommand}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Button.Triggers>
                                        </Button>
                                        
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                        
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
```

Every model inside the Collection implement's INPC and when I subscribe to the PropertyChangedEvent, it fires when the property of the model is changed.

When the user "Clicks the Button, to Accept a proposal, the "AcceptProposal command is fired, and here is the content of that command:"

```
async Task AcceptProposal(ProposalModel proposal)
    {
        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;
```

// This is where I change the state of the model whose button was clicked. But the change is not reflected in the UI
                Proposals.Where(prop => prop.Id == proposal.Id).FirstOrDefault().State = ProposalStates.Approved;

```
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DataTrigger setters are having no effect because you've already set local values on the button which [take precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) over triggers.

You need to set default values in a style instead

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">

            <Setter Property="Text"    Value="{markupExtensions:Translate Accept}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=BindingContext.AcceptProposalCommand, Source={x:Reference _myAnnDetailsPageklas}}" />

         <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=State}" Value="{x:Static models:ProposalStates.Approved}">

                 <Setter Property="Text"    Value="{markupExtensions:Translate Reject}"/>
                 <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Source={x:Reference _myAnnDetailsPageklas}, Path=BindingContext.RejectProposalCommand}"/>

             </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</Button>
```

ps. Did you mean "Text" or "Content" for the button text?

Comment: Thanks but this makes it worse, now when I run the app, the button is empty with no text and the command is not binded